# Installing a program on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, download, terminal, installation

I'm really new to this kind of thing, so I need some help. Can somebody please provide me with step-by-step instructions for installing this program (ds9) on Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit?

http://hea-www.harvard.edu/RD/ds9/site/Beta.html

Comment: Did you try simply downloading the Linux binary and running it? Seems pretty straightforward...

Comment: Yeah. I unzipped the .tar.gz file, and now I'm stuck. It even pulls ds9 out as an application, but when I try to simply run it I get the error: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your file is a binary

```
edu@debian:~$ file ds9 
ds9: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
edu@debian:~$
```

you only need to download, extract it and run:

```
edu@debian:~$./ds9
```

This was probably a question for another stackexchange site, like superuser.

edit: as regarding to your comment about the library

You probably need this package:

```
libxss1 - X11 Screen Saver extension library
```

so install it:

```
apt-get install libxss1
```